# Forcing Iframe into a collapse bootstrap component to fit screen

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I am using an Accordion Collapse bootstrap component to display two collapse items in a page. The first collapse item is collapsed by default and the second one has in it body an iframe which display a pdf document. I need the second collapsible item to fit the left height of the screen. I tried to achieve it with flex boxes but seems there is an issue with the collapse event and the flex box. I would appreciate any help.

This is my fiddle example:

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/651vfxk8/)

The following picture depicts the undesired behaviour:
[image]

```
<vp-leftpanel>
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-
      multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                {{panelHeadingData}}
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div *ngIf="candidate.hasEmailSourceData">

                .....

            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        {{panelHeadingResume}}
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select class="form-control" (change)='loadDocument($event.target.value)'>
                        <option [value]="d.id" *ngFor="let d of candidate.candidateDocuments">{{d.friendlyName}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div *ngIf="candidate.candidateDocuments.length > 0" class="apply-flex">
                <iframe [src]="documentSelectedPathSafe" type="application/pdf" ></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  </vp-leftpanel>
```

Comment: Actually, your question is not clear as what your demand is. I tried it and working absolutely fine what problem you're facing

Comment: @GajendraSingh What u mean with it is working absolutely fine. Could u share what is that you tried.

Answer (score 1):

To enable that with Flexbox is somewhat complicated.

In this [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/651vfxk8/5/) I created/applied the below classes to accomplish it, fully dynamic, thought this will break the accordion's showing/hiding

```
.fullvh {
  height: 100vh;
}
.flex-box-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.pos-relative {
  position: relative;
}
/* as it didn't work adding "flex-box-col flex-grow" to this
   elements class, I added it using its ID #collapseTwo */
#collapseTwo {         
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.pos-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

An alternative, in this [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/651vfxk8/6/), that will not break the accordion, would instead be to give the `iframe` a height combining viewport units `vh` and CSS `calc()`. Even if the fixed height `160px` is somewhat known, it is still less dynamic than the previous sample.

```
#collapseTwo iframe {
  height: calc(100vh - 160px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

Additionally, one can fix the script in the first sample, or add a calculation for the script in the second, to get the exact height, or swap to Bootstrap 4, which is based on Flexbox.

Swapping to Bootstrap 4 might not solve it without some adjustments, so test it thoroughly before starting up with a migration.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, really appreciate it. The first one definitely doesnt work in the context i need it. The second one is a good alternative but i am not still happy with a fixed height. I will wait to see if probably someone comes out with another potential solution. For now i have up-voted your answer.

Comment: @D.B I have covered the 3 possible ways to do this, and the 2 best options are, IMHO, to either extend the script to actually detect and set the height, or use Boostrap 4, which still might need some adjustments.

Comment: @D.B I have covered the available options to reach the closest possible what can be done using CSS alone. Do you find this good enough to also be accepted?

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the CSS `height=100%` with `max-height: 200px;`.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution is seems to be more complex than that.

Comment: Im answering in long expalanation, but somehow, someone edit my answer and it become that short.. Am I wrong? I tried in my pc first bfore post the answer..